# Converting to conjunctive normal form

Tags: boolean, logic

I'm  trying to convert this to conjunctive normal form: `∧0≤i<n ∨0≤j1,j2<n (Ci,j1 ∧ Ci,j2)`
which is proving a lot more difficult than I expected.

I can't seem to get rid of the AND nested the deepest without introducing NOTs to non-literals. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Take a look here: [http://math.stackexchange.com/q/214338]

Comment: The formula is not well formed, is there something missing before the first conjunction? What does "Ci,j1" mean?